# Excel find next match in table column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, match

I am trying to find the next matching row in a table (not just a range) that matches the current cell's value. I have tried to pass in the column from the next row to the end of the column but cannot get it to work. All ideas are welcome!  E.g.

```
Current idea that doesnt work: =MATCH([@Value],OFFSET([@Value],1,0):[Value])

Example data:
Row    Value    Next_Match
 1       1        #N/a
 2       2          4
 3       3          6
 4       2          5
 5       2        #N/a
 6       3        #N/a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=OFFSET(B3,MATCH(B3,B4:B$100,0),-1)
```

assuming B100 is the last row and you want to match only afterwards... Otherwise use B2:B100 etc

Oh and data is in Columns A,B,C

Although the perfectionist in me rather's

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B3,B4:B16,0)),"Last",OFFSET(B3,MATCH(B3,B4:B16,0),-1))
```

Comment: Hi @BryanDavies. The table will be increasing all the time so I am looking for the formula to look to the bottom of the column automatically rather than a hard coded number of rows below - is this possible?

Comment: There is, I just cant remember it...

But in saying that, just put in a mill or something. It wont matter to that formulla

Comment: edit: google says

=min(row(data))-rows(data)-1

https://exceljet.net/formula/last-row-number-in-range

Comment: I managed to use INDIRECT("B"&(ROW()+1)&":B"&COUNTA(B:B)) in the end - thanks for your help!